# Pushing Table Views, selecting one row at a time.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to push a tableview in a tableview. My main purpose is whenever a user     presses on a cell, it will go into a selected data I want to to show. In others words, just     an example, whenever I press "2014" I want to show F Type, A8.... , But NOT Sunfire, since there is no 2014 "Sunfire..." Well every time  I press any row in the RootTableViewController, I always calls the FirstArray. Help Please...

```
#import "PetsTableViewController.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface PetsTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation PetsTableViewController
@synthesize petsInt; 
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self)    {    }
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

FirstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
            initWithObjects:@"F-Type", @"A8", @"Prius", nil];

SecondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
            initWithObjects:@"S-Type", @"Silverado", @"A8", nil];


ThirdArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
            initWithObjects:@"S type", @"Sunfire", nil];

[super viewDidLoad];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:         (NSInteger)section
{

if (petsInt == 0)
    return [FirstArray count];
if (petsInt == 1)
    return [SecondArray count];
if (petsInt == 2)
    return [ThirdArray count];
[self.tableView reloadData];
return 0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"You";


 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];


if (cell == nil)    {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if (petsInt == 0)
    cell.textLabel.text = [FirstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (petsInt == 1)
cell.textLabel.text = [SecondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (petsInt == 2)
cell.textLabel.text = [ThirdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: Where do you assign the value of `petsInt`?

Comment: I didn't get it can you edit your post to make it clearer?

Comment: PetsInt is just an integer I put in. I'm not sure if it makes sense to to it in, I was following a tutorial. Anyway, to make it more understandable I want to Push a certain Make of a car, like Jaguar, and get another table view of its models, like F-type, S-type, X-Type....